# Div Expand From Specify Top Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show my pop up div with expanding on specify top position.

But I should open the pop up on the main page's center, I don't know how to do that.

For now, I only can do is expanding from main page's center to top and bottom which is depends on pop-up's height.

Here's what I want it to do:

```
┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐  │            
│                          │
│                          │             
│                          │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘                        

┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐  │
│ │popup div            │  │
│                          │
│                          │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐  │
│ │popup div            │  │
│ │                     │  │
│ └─────────────────────┘  │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

But now:

```
┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│                          │
│                          │
│                          │
│ │                     │  │
│                          │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘                        

┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│                          │
│ │popup div            │  │
│ │                     │  │
│ │                     │  │
│                          │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────────────┐
│Main Page                 │
│ ┌─────────────────────┐  │
│ │popup div            │  │
│ │                     │  │
│ │                     │  │
│ └─────────────────────┘  │
│                          │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Here's my code.

```css
.popupLayer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 76%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 4s ease-in;
    height: 0; // Animation works if you set initial height
}
```

```js
var expandDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('popupLayer')[0];
expandDiv.style.display = 'block';
expandDiv.style.top = '55%';
setTimeout(function() {
    expandDiv.style.height = '55%'; 
}, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
    ... // some elements including popup div..
    <div class = 'popupLayer'>  
          ...// popuplayer body
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `transform: translate(-50%, -55%)`

What is happening in your case

your `transform` property is setting div in center position of parent div
As height is 0 it will start from exact center position and as height increases it browser makes it to be exact center of parent

you have to specify exact top position and remove `transform` property

```js
var expandDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('popupLayer')[0];
expandDiv.style.display = 'block';
expandDiv.style.top = '27.5%';
setTimeout(function() {
    expandDiv.style.height = '55%'; 
}, 1000);
```

```css
.popupLayer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 76%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 4s ease-in;
    height: 0; // Animation works if you set initial height
}
```

```html
<div class = 'popupLayer'>  
          ...// popuplayer body
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I remove transform: translate(-50%, -55%), it doesn't go to center.

How can I let it go to center then?

Comment: Let me see this. You want the top 55% and transform it to the center.... why don't you set top 27.5%. Then it will start from 27.5% and will increase it's height.... And also keep `transform` for X axis